# How to check if current user has logged in before

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I'm using parse.com as the backend of my iOS application.
In my app, I'm creating anonymous users and allowing my app users to login with either Twitter or Facebook. When a user logs in using either of these utilities, I'd like to know if he had logged in previously. How can I conclude this?

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a workaround that creates a last login NSDate as a PFObject under the currentUser object or by incorporating the userID into the parent object. When the user logs in, check for this PFObject with a query. If it doesn't exist, they are new users. Then you can set the property for future login tracking.

```
PFObject *loginObj = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"LastLoginObject"];
[loginObj setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"CurrentUser"];
[loginObj setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"LastLoginDate"];
[loginObj save];
```